# Symfony functional test - assertion for a table

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I just want to run a few assertions on the HTML data below. Inside an `$this->assertEquals(1, ..., "failure");` I have tried:

```
$crawler->filter('table.table-general > tr > td:contains("<strong>Task ID</strong> 6")')
$crawler->filter('table.table-general > tr > td:contains("<strong>Customer</strong> ABC Inc.")')
$crawler->filter('table.table-general > tr > td:contains("<strong>Location</strong> New York City")')
$crawler->filter('table.table-general > tr > td:contains("<strong>Phone Number</strong> 555-1234")')
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work (assertions fail). What am I doing wrong?

```
<table class="table table-curved table-general">
    <tr>
            <td rowspan="5" width="10%" id="general-task-id"><strong>Task ID</strong><br /><h3>6</h3></td>
            <td width="30%"><strong>Customer</strong> ABC Inc.</td>
            <td width="30%"><strong>Location</strong> New York City</td>
            <td width="30%"><strong>Phone Number</strong> 555-1234</td>
    </tr>

    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter method use the CssSelector and the contains do an xpath selection based on the node, so is not possible to check for other html tag inside.
Here a working solution for your example:

```
$i = $crawler->filter('table.table-general > tr > td > strong:contains("Task ID")')->count();
$this->assertEquals(1, $i);

$i = $crawler->filter('table.table-general > tr > td > h3:contains("6")')->count();
$this->assertEquals(1, $i);

    $i = $crawler->filter('table.table-general > tr > td > strong:contains("Customer")')->count();
    $this->assertEquals(1, $i);

    $i = $crawler->filter('table.table-general > tr > td:contains("ABC Inc.")')->count();
    $this->assertEquals(1, $i);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Bizarely what ended up fixing it was `contains("Location New York City")` - it seems to ignore the html tags.

Comment: Hi @b85411 exactly what i mean, you tried my code? It will fix your question?

Comment: Looking at your code, the tests could possibly pass even if the data is not correct though. For example, say the page rendered `<strong>Task ID</strong> ABC Inc.` - with your example, that would still pass because both Task ID and ABC Inc. are found even though they shouldn't be in the same `<td>`?

Comment: @b85411 your test seems too couple to the html... what you do if your designer restyle your site? your must rewrite all the functional test? Take a look at the [best practice](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/tests.html#functional-tests)

Comment: But what if the designer makes a mistake while restyling and puts the customer data next to Task ID? With my approach, that error would be picked up :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first assertion looks for `<strong>Task ID</strong> 6` but in fact your HTML says `<strong>Task ID</strong><br /><h3>6</h3>`

Comment: normally, unit tests stop execution after the first fail. correct your test and execute it again to see if the rest works.

Comment: No luck. Unfortunately that didn't fix it :(